# XSLT: How to write an `<xsl:apply-templates/>` for matching nodes with templates with modes and without modes without disturbing the order?

Tags: xml, xslt

Suppose I have the following XML:

```
<root>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
    <a>3</a>
    <c>4</c>
    <a>5</a>
    <a>6</a>
    <b>7</b>
    <a>8</a>
    <c>9</c>
</root>
```

Consider the following XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="a | b | c"/>    <!-- matches node 'b' with a non-mode template instead of the one with mode="test" -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
    <xsl:text> ignore </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b" mode="test">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

I am trying to write a XSL template call which will match all the nodes inside the root node with its corresponding template but the node `b` should be matched with a template with `mode="test"`. The order of the node handling should not be disturbed.

The desired output is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if this will be applicable to you. Instead of

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="a | b | c"/>
</xsl:template>
```

do

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name()='a'">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="name()='b'">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="test"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="name()='c'">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would define a new mode, and then redirect it as appropriate:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="a | b | c" mode="new"/>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a|c" mode="new">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b" mode="new">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="test"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Another solution is to define template rules that apply in more than one mode, so the "unnamed mode" templates for a and c would also apply to mode "new", while the mode="test" template for b would also apply to mode "new". IIRC this requires XSLT 2.0 (you don't say which version you are using - please do so in future).